# Python isnt recognized in cmd and i cant use pip

Tags: python, windows

im pretty new to coding and stuff but for whatever reason, python, pip or even doing cd C:\Python38\scripts cmd will just tell me the directory isnt found or that it isnt a command, i did echo %PATH% and it is in there. (this is probably a really simple solution, im not advanced with stuff like this at all)

Comment: _ven doing cd C:\Python38\scripts doesn't work at al_ Telling us that it "doesn't work" is not very helpful.  If you're getting error messages, show us.

Comment: @John Gordon my bad, the point is that cmd doesnt recognize that python is installed at all even though it is in PATH

Comment: We need to see the command you typed, the actual error messages, your PATH variable, and the contents of the directory where you expect python to be found.  Without those details, all we can say is "You must have done something wrong."

Comment: How did you install Python and are you following some specific guide telling you to use `c:\python38\ ` ? By default python.org should guide you to download 3.10, same if you install through Microsoft Store.

Comment: @margusl i did install python 3.8, i was told its the one that wont break a certain program im using to learn ML

Answer (score 0):

Open a new CMD with the start menu

go to the location where python is installed.

press on the Path next to Search Bar.

Copy, back to CMD, cd (paste)

This will set the working directory to where python is installed.

You can test now with `python` command, and check it it works , then the issue is only path related.

Now for checking with Path, You will need to add the complete path to the `python.exe` the one you just copied into CMD.

For example

`C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` at this path there will be a `python.exe` where You can execute with CMD.

If you have an issue with the path and have to update to the new one, Make sure to start a new CMD window to take the effects of the Path update.

Comment: i tried that and it says “No such file or directory.” i kept looking over it and i didnt misspell anything

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add python in the PATH variable to access python from cmd in windows.

Please see the article at this link [Adding python to Path](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)

Post that you would be able to access pip from cmd/ use pip within cmd

Comment: i have done that before, and i would run echo %PATH% and i would see C:\Python38 in the path.